# How do you name a shorthand for a template of a specific type?

Tags: c++, templates

Say I often use a template class `Foo` with template type `int` very often:

```
Foo<int> number;
Foo<int> location;
...
```

I know there is a way to make this prettier by defining a name for this specific template type so I can have equivalent (but prettier) code like so:

```
FooInt number;
FooInt location;
...
```

I believe this can be done with the compiler directive `#define` but I'm not sure on the specifics. Alternatively, is there a way to just implement a new class `FooInt` that is defined to be a `Foo<int>`?

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but `IFoo` is not really a great idea of a name here... In many coding standards it suggests an abstract interface, which it certainly isn't. `FooInt` perhaps? Just saying...

Comment: @syam I updated the question so as not to confuse anyone. Good catch.

Comment: look into `std::string` sometime

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a regular `typedef` to create aliases for template types when all of the parameters are fixed:

```
typedef Foo<int> FooInt;
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is an alias:

```
using FooInt = Foo<int>;
```

Note, this is only available in C++11.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the two versions allready mentioned, I would suggest `Foo<int>`. It is self documenting. Others have to understand it and if you look at your own code later (lets say 2 years) you have to understand it, too. In these cases `Foo<int>` is better than the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` is the answer, but as a complement of information...

> Alternatively, is there a way to just implement a new class FooInt
>   that is defined to be a Foo of Int ?

Yes, simply declare your specialized class as follows :

```
class FooInt : public Foo<int> {
}
```

Note : I am note saying that this is a good way to go, but only that this is doable.

Comment: Note that using this code, FooInt will clearly not be the same as Foo<int>.

Comment: Yes definitely, I was just treating here the "alternatively" part. Take that as complement of information, not an answer ;-)

Comment: Yes I was in `java` mood tonight ;-) Thanks.